# Background job triggering afterDelete

Tags: parse-platform

I need to delete a record from inside of a background job. When I do that, it triggers the afterDelete function, which is great because I have a bit of logic in afterDelete, but it fails because it doesn't have the context of a request.user, which I use in my afterDelete logic.

I need to schedule this job to run from my dashboard – I'm not using the REST endpoint.

Is there a way to pass that context to afterDelete? How do I handle the situation?

**Edit:** This is all happening inside the context of Cloud Code. No Parse Android/iOS SDK is being used.

Comment: Maybe use a [broadcast receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that calls `afterDelete` to get a usable context.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear in the question. This is all in context of Cloud Code. Nothing is getting initiated from the client. Also, I'm not using Parse's Android or iOS SDKs.

Comment: Would you give some more details of your reasoning? It would help with finding a solution.